# OnItemTouchListener for Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, ontouchlistener

The `OnItemClickListener()` send an action on touch UP.
I need to receive the action after touch DOWN.

So I want to create an `OnItemTouchListener()`, the problem is I don't know you the get the current position of the touched view.

Here my code :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (customTouchListener != null))
        {
           // int position = ??
           customTouchListener.onTouch(v, event, position);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: event.getX and event.getY ?

Comment: Hmmm it's seems to be durty...

Comment: event is the touch event. getX and getY return the coordinates of this touch event. Why do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `settag()` function to set tag for each list item with the item positon. hope this will help you.